# Is it possible to interfere in the headers of the MAC protocol in wifi using madwifi driver?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, driver

I'm working with a madwifi ath5k driver. basically what i'm trying to do is to change some things in the behavior of the MAC protocol in order to implement network coding. 
in some parts of my project i need to add some field to the headers of the 802.11 MAC protocol, and my questions are:

1. is it possible to add fields in the middle of the frame headers, and extend the total frame length? i've tried to add 20 bytes after the sequence number field, but it cause some problems (pinging stop working).
2. if it's possible, which data structures should be changes and how?

thanks!

Omer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify or add to 802.11 MAC headers, each field there has a specific size and location. If you change that, you're breaking the protocol. This doesn't mean it's wrong, it just means you're implementing a different protocol. In order to work it has to be implemented by all the parties participating in the communication (including mediators, such as APs). If you want to be 802.11-compliant, you need to add any proprietary information inside frame body, not inside the header. It's usually done via proprietary Information Elements that are parsed by the corresponding protocol extensions, such as CCX.

Comment: i think that i was not clear enough about that part :) i'm modifying the existing protocol, so it's actually not WiFi anymore.. my question is more about the technical part of this. i can't find the variables that should be modified. i know that there is a way to set the value of the header length but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You can't configure header length. Yes, it can be different but the difference is coupled with the frame type and subtype and contains only the relevant fields. E.g., RTS frame header has 16 bytes, while CTS frame header has only 14 bytes. If you violate frame header format, you're breaking the protocol - if you do that, you can't rely on anything that the original protocol provides. This is also the reason your pings don't work, ping protocol needs the underlying 802.11 protocol to operate (or a valid substitute).